# O recurso de "times" virá para o StackOverflow em português também?

Tags: suporte, novo-recurso

O StackOverflow conta agora com um tipo de grupo de usuários, chamado de [**times**](https://stackoverflow.com/teams/). Eu entendi "mais ou menos" como isso funciona e para que serve, gostaria de saber se nossa comunidade também terá isso.

Embora nenhuma palavra desse recurso esteja nas [**strings que faltam traduzir**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/translation/missing), existem várias que estão presentes no Transifex.

Comment: Pra que serve esse times?

Comment: @DiegoF É parecido com o conceito de Grupos no LinkedIn ou no Facebook. Usuários podem criar "times" e adicionar outros usuários que trabalham num mesmo projeto ou empresa, que participam de uma mesma comunidade, etc. Até onde eu sei, o recurso por enquanto está disponível só no SO original e não em outros sites da rede, mas existe a possibilidade de expansão, sendo só uma questão de tempo até refinar a novidade.

Comment: times == equipas/grupos para pt_PT.

Comment: Fiquei curioso para saber qual a funcionalidade desse recurso , afinal e só pra montar um time e ponto final : s ?

Comment: @stringNome, A SO/SE está criando novas ferramentas e unificado certas coisas, o teams é uma dessas novidades tem docs e o developer story. Tem uns links longos sobre cada uma => [The Goal of Teams: Our Follow-Up to Your Questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308601/1342547), [The Developer Story](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/319524/1342547) e [Warlords of Documentation](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/306213/1342547)

Comment: As *Equipes* de trabalho que conheço fazem *Times* pra jogar futebol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta padrão pra todas essas coisas novas é: **Talvez**.

Esse não é um "talvez" do tipo "só se vocês se comportarem", ou "só se pedirem bastante". Criar essas funcionalidades novas (Docs, Teams, Dev Story) dá bastante trabalho, como alguns de vocês podem ter acompanhado nos respectivos posts. Estamos dedicados à essas ferramentas há algum tempo já, trabalhando arduamente para que elas tragam para a comunidade os benefícios que esperamos.

São coisas grandes e novas, que a gente nunca tentou antes e precisa trabalhar bastante pra que sejam bem recebidas e bem sucedidas. Apesar de algumas delas estarem em estágio bem avançado de desenvolvimento, isso não quer dizer que coisas não possam mudar após o lançamento. Há muito que a gente ainda não sabe sobre como essas novidades vão funcionar e como vão ser usadas.

E é por isso que decidimos pensar sobre a internacionalização só *depois* que elas estiverem mais maduras. Não teríamos condição de tomar conta de tanta coisa ao mesmo tempo. Lançar Teams (ou Docs, ou Story) em português (ou espanhol, ou japonês, ou russo) não é só uma questão de traduzir as strings. Temos também que ouvir vocês - coisa que nem sempre conseguimos fazer aqui, por exemplo.

Queremos que todas as essas coisas estejam em todos os sites internacionais, mas não podemos garantir nada por enquanto, nem dar nenhuma previsão.